# How can I create key binding with Java in Console?

Tags: java, linux, console

I have been given an assignment where i have to create a game in console, it is only a simple one but none the less I have decided i need to use KeyBindings. I have seen some tutorials online but they are all based around a GUI interface, is this possible in Console? any good documentation to how I could do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Key binding in Java is restricted to GUI elements that extend JComponent, as you already found.

You can still use key bindings in AWT without swing, as seen here: [How do you make key bindings for a java.awt.Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434740/how-do-you-make-key-bindings-for-a-java-awt-frame)

However, if you want to use key bindings directly on a console, you're out of luck. The console window itself is not owned by the java runtime, and is generally controlled by the OS (cmd.exe on Windows and /bin/bash or /bin/sh on UNIX systems).

You may be able to get "some" of the functionality you need from a library like JLine. But even that is restricted to things that the console window passes to the JVM. http://jline.sourceforge.net/